# How to calculate modulus of large numbers?

Tags: math, modulo

How to calculate modulus of 5^55 modulus 221 without much use of calculator?

I guess there are some simple principles in number theory in cryptography to calculate such things.

Comment: Here is an explanation: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/39012

Comment: the devx link is not of much use, there are other simple methods in number theory for such things, AFAIK.

Comment: close for what, have you ever read cryptography?

Comment: @Priyank Bolia: Don't worry, it's unlikely this question will be closed. It's a good question. If it is closed, there will be plenty of people voting to reopen.

Comment: Yeah, many of us are aware that sometimes computer science involves mathematics.

Comment: Math Overflow would be another place to post this kind of question: http://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @JB King: MathOverflow is for mathematics at the graduate-level and higher; this question would be frowned upon there.

Comment: Related: [https://www.quora.com/Whats-an-efficient-algorithm-to-convert-the-base-of-a-BIG-number](https://www.quora.com/Whats-an-efficient-algorithm-to-convert-the-base-of-a-BIG-number)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Okay, so you want to calculate `a^b mod m`. First we'll take a naive approach and then see how we can refine it.

First, reduce `a mod m`. That means, find a number `a1` so that `0 <= a1 < m` and `a = a1 mod m`. Then repeatedly in a loop multiply by `a1` and reduce again `mod m`. Thus, in pseudocode:

```
a1 = a reduced mod m
p = 1
for(int i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
    p *= a1
    p = p reduced mod m
}
```

By doing this, we avoid numbers larger than `m^2`. This is the key. The reason we avoid numbers larger than `m^2` is because at every step `0 <= p < m` and `0 <= a1 < m`.

As an example, let's compute `5^55 mod 221`. First, `5` is already reduced `mod 221`.

1. `1 * 5 = 5 mod 221`
2. `5 * 5 = 25 mod 221`
3. `25 * 5 = 125 mod 221`
4. `125 * 5 = 183 mod 221`
5. `183 * 5 = 31 mod 221`
6. `31 * 5 = 155 mod 221`
7. `155 * 5 = 112 mod 221`
8. `112 * 5 = 118 mod 221`
9. `118 * 5 = 148 mod 221`
10. `148 * 5 = 77 mod 221`
11. `77 * 5 = 164 mod 221`
12. `164 * 5 = 157 mod 221`
13. `157 * 5 = 122 mod 221`
14. `122 * 5 = 168 mod 221`
15. `168 * 5 = 177 mod 221`
16. `177 * 5 = 1 mod 221`
17. `1 * 5 = 5 mod 221`
18. `5 * 5 = 25 mod 221`
19. `25 * 5 = 125 mod 221`
20. `125 * 5 = 183 mod 221`
21. `183 * 5 = 31 mod 221`
22. `31 * 5 = 155 mod 221`
23. `155 * 5 = 112 mod 221`
24. `112 * 5 = 118 mod 221`
25. `118 * 5 = 148 mod 221`
26. `148 * 5 = 77 mod 221`
27. `77 * 5 = 164 mod 221`
28. `164 * 5 = 157 mod 221`
29. `157 * 5 = 122 mod 221`
30. `122 * 5 = 168 mod 221`
31. `168 * 5 = 177 mod 221`
32. `177 * 5 = 1 mod 221`
33. `1 * 5 = 5 mod 221`
34. `5 * 5 = 25 mod 221`
35. `25 * 5 = 125 mod 221`
36. `125 * 5 = 183 mod 221`
37. `183 * 5 = 31 mod 221`
38. `31 * 5 = 155 mod 221`
39. `155 * 5 = 112 mod 221`
40. `112 * 5 = 118 mod 221`
41. `118 * 5 = 148 mod 221`
42. `148 * 5 = 77 mod 221`
43. `77 * 5 = 164 mod 221`
44. `164 * 5 = 157 mod 221`
45. `157 * 5 = 122 mod 221`
46. `122 * 5 = 168 mod 221`
47. `168 * 5 = 177 mod 221`
48. `177 * 5 = 1 mod 221`
49. `1 * 5 = 5 mod 221`
50. `5 * 5 = 25 mod 221`
51. `25 * 5 = 125 mod 221`
52. `125 * 5 = 183 mod 221`
53. `183 * 5 = 31 mod 221`
54. `31 * 5 = 155 mod 221`
55. `155 * 5 = 112 mod 221`

Therefore, `5^55 = 112 mod 221`.

Now, we can improve this by using [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring); this is the famous trick wherein we reduce exponentiation to requiring only `log b` multiplications instead of `b`. Note that with the algorithm that I described above, the exponentiation by squaring improvement, you end up with the [right-to-left binary method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method).

```
a1 = a reduced mod m
p = 1
while (b > 0) {
     if (b is odd) {
         p *= a1
         p = p reduced mod m
     }
     b /= 2
     a1 = (a1 * a1) reduced mod m
}
```

Thus, since 55 = 110111 in binary

1. `1 * (5^1  mod 221) = 5 mod 221`
2. `5 * (5^2  mod 221) = 125 mod 221`
3. `125 * (5^4  mod 221) = 112 mod 221`
4. `112 * (5^16  mod 221) = 112 mod 221`
5. `112 * (5^32  mod 221) = 112 mod 221`

Therefore the answer is `5^55 = 112 mod 221`. The reason this works is because

```
55 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 16 + 32
```

so that

```
5^55 = 5^(1 + 2 + 4 + 16 + 32) mod 221
     = 5^1 * 5^2 * 5^4 * 5^16 * 5^32 mod 221
     = 5 * 25 * 183 * 1 * 1 mod 221
     = 22875 mod 221
     = 112 mod 221
```

In the step where we calculate `5^1 mod 221`, `5^2 mod 221`, etc. we note that `5^(2^k)` = `5^(2^(k-1)) * 5^(2^(k-1))` because `2^k = 2^(k-1) + 2^(k-1)` so that we can first compute `5^1` and reduce `mod 221`, then square this and reduce `mod 221` to obtain `5^2 mod 221`, etc.

The above algorithm formalizes this idea.

Comment: Well, most programming languages have a built-in operator for this. For example, in C-derived languages, the `%` operator is the modulus operator. Thus, `int p = 625 % 221` would assign `183` to `p`. You can achieve the same functionality by dividing `625` by `221` as integer division and getting the answer `2`. Then you take `625 - 2 * 221` to get the remainder. In this case `625 - 2 * 221 = 183` which is the answer.

Comment: this takes too much multiplication 54 times, is  there even faster method.

Comment: Yes, as I described in the paragraph at the end you do exponentiation by squaring.

Comment: You can actually do much better than exponentiation by squaring, especially in the large-exponent case. Notice that you found that `5^16 == 1 (mod 221)`. Therefore, `5^k == 5^(k%16) (mod 221)`.

Comment: @Jefromi, is there an easy way to find the period of a^b mod c? By easy of course, I mean sublogarithmic.

Comment: If you only need the order of one such $a$, there's no way besides iteration. However, with large enough exponents, it's still going to be worth it (on average), or with repeated calculations. I believe if you wanted the orders of *all* $a$, you could work something out though...

Comment: @Jason: you have written: *First, reduce a mod m. That means, find a number a1 so that 0 <= a1 < m and a = a1 mod m.* It looks like the last equation contains a typo, shouldn't it be *a1 = a mod m* instead?

Comment: @Jason: why do you use *a reduced mod m*? It looks like *a mod m* perfectly explains what do you want to do, doesn't it?

Comment: @Jason for the most part, if you just added ";" (and a few other characters) to your pseudocode, it would be C.

Comment: i'm maybe a bit braindead atm, but WHY can you apply the modulo function on each 'step'

Answer (score 30):

To add to Jason's answer:

You can speed the process up (which might be helpful for very large exponents) using the binary expansion of the exponent. First calculate 5, 5^2, 5^4, 5^8 mod 221 - you do this by repeated squaring:

```
 5^1 = 5(mod 221)
 5^2 = 5^2 (mod 221) = 25(mod 221)
 5^4 = (5^2)^2 = 25^2(mod 221) = 625 (mod 221) = 183(mod221)
 5^8 = (5^4)^2 = 183^2(mod 221) = 33489 (mod 221) = 118(mod 221)
5^16 = (5^8)^2 = 118^2(mod 221) = 13924 (mod 221) = 1(mod 221)
5^32 = (5^16)^2 = 1^2(mod 221) = 1(mod 221)
```

Now we can write

```
55 = 1 + 2 + 4 + 16 + 32

so 5^55 = 5^1 * 5^2 * 5^4 * 5^16 * 5^32 
        = 5   * 25  * 625 * 1    * 1 (mod 221)
        = 125 * 625 (mod 221)
        = 125 * 183 (mod 183) - because 625 = 183 (mod 221)
        = 22875 ( mod 221)
        = 112 (mod 221)
```

You can see how for very large exponents this will be much faster (I believe it's log as opposed to linear in b, but not certain.)

Comment: this is even better explanation

Comment: I suspect that it's actually much faster (in general) to avoid the exponentiation by squaring, and instead search directly for the least exponent $k$ such that $5^k == 5 (mod 221)$. This does of course depend on size of exponent versus modulus, but once you have that exponent, you just need a single calculation (exponent mod k) and lookup. Note it's also therefore definitely better if you need to repeat similar calculations. (You can't in general look for $a^k == 1 (mod 221)$ since this only happens if $a$ and 221 are relatively prime)

Comment: well, no, in general finding the least exponent with that property is much slower than sqaure-and-multiply. But if you know the factorization of the modulus then you can easily compute the carmichael lambda function which is a mutliple of your k.

Answer (score 12):

```
/* The algorithm is from the book "Discrete Mathematics and Its
   Applications 5th Edition" by Kenneth H. Rosen.
   (base^exp)%mod
*/

int modular(int base, unsigned int exp, unsigned int mod)
{
    int x = 1;
    int power = base % mod;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8; i++) {
        int least_sig_bit = 0x00000001 & (exp >> i);
        if (least_sig_bit)
            x = (x * power) % mod;
        power = (power * power) % mod;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: `x * power` and `power * power` are subject to overflow when `mod*mod > UINT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: Yep @chux is right, we should take mod even during x * power and power * power.

Comment: @jack_1729 Code can use a wider integer type with `x * power` to avoid OF. 
 If none available, code can use [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187257/modular-exponentiation-without-range-restriction).

Answer (score 3):

```
5^55 mod221

= (   5^10         * 5^10         * 5^10         * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221    

= ( ( 5^10) mod221 * 5^10         * 5^10         * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= (   77           * 5^10         * 5^10         * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221   

= ( ( 77           * 5^10) mod221 * 5^10         * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= (   183                         * 5^10         * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= ( ( 183                         * 5^10) mod221 * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= (   168                                        * 5^10          * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= ( ( 168                                        * 5^10) mod 221 * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= (   118                                                        * 5^10          * 5^5) mod221 

= ( ( 118                                                        * 5^10) mod 221 * 5^5) mod221 

= (   25                                                                         * 5^5) mod221 

=     112
```

Comment: Is this slower than doing it the exponentiation way?

Answer (score 2):

[Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) comes to mind as an initial point as 221 = 13 * 17.  So, break this down into 2 parts that get combined in the end, one for mod 13 and one for mod 17.  Second, I believe there is some proof of a^(p-1) = 1 mod p for all non zero a which also helps reduce your problem as 5^55 becomes 5^3 for the mod 13 case as 13*4=52.  If you look under the subject of "Finite Fields" you may find some good results on how to solve this.

EDIT: The reason I mention the factors is that this creates a way to factor zero into non-zero elements as if you tried something like 13^2 * 17^4 mod 221, the answer is zero since 13*17=221.  A lot of large numbers aren't going to be prime, though there are ways to find large primes as they are used a lot in cryptography and other areas within Mathematics.

Comment: well I don't know the factorials in the first place, and I am trying to prove that the number is a prime, using Miller Rabin Algorithm. So, I am at the opposite end.

Comment: There aren't any factorials here, but there is a factorization which is different.  The factorial of an integer n is defined as the product of all positive integers less than n,e.g. 2!=2, 3!=6, etc. and is often expressed using the ! symbol.  Factorization is different and there isn't a common symbol used to express an integer being factored.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is modular exponentiation, specifically modular binary exponentiation. This [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) has pseudocode.

Answer (score 2):

This is part of code I made for IBAN validation. Feel free to use.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int modulo = 97;
        string input = Reverse("100020778788920323232343433");
        int result = 0;
        int lastRowValue = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            // Calculating the modulus of a large number Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number                                                                        
            if (i > 0)
            {
                lastRowValue = ModuloByDigits(lastRowValue, modulo);
            }
            result += lastRowValue * int.Parse(input[i].ToString());
        }
        result = result % modulo;
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result: {0}", result));            
    }

    public static int ModuloByDigits(int previousValue, int modulo)
    {
        // Calculating the modulus of a large number Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number                        
        return ((previousValue * 10) % modulo);
    }
    public static string Reverse(string input)
    {
        char[] arr = input.ToCharArray();
        Array.Reverse(arr);
        return new string(arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Jason's answer in Java (note `i < exp`).

```
private static void testModulus() {
    int bse = 5, exp = 55, mod = 221;

    int a1 = bse % mod;
    int p = 1;

    System.out.println("1. " + (p % mod) + " * " + bse + " = " + (p % mod) * bse + " mod " + mod);

    for (int i = 1; i < exp; i++) {
        p *= a1;
        System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + (p % mod) + " * " + bse + " = " + ((p % mod) * bse) % mod + " mod " + mod);
        p = (p % mod);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just provide another implementation of Jason's answer by C.

After discussing with my classmates, based on Jason's explanation, I like the recursive version more if you don't care about the performance very much:

For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int mypow( int base, int pow, int mod ){
    if( pow == 0 ) return 1;
    if( pow % 2 == 0 ){
        int tmp = mypow( base, pow >> 1, mod );
        return tmp * tmp % mod;
    }
    else{
        return base * mypow( base, pow - 1, mod ) % mod;
    }
}

int main(){
    printf("%d", mypow(5,55,221));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called modular exponentiation(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

Let's assume you have the following expression:

```
19 ^ 3 mod 7
```

Instead of powering 19 directly you can do the following:

```
(((19 mod 7) * 19) mod 7) * 19) mod 7
```

But this can take also a long time due to a lot of sequential multipliations and so you can multiply on squared values:

```
x mod N -> x ^ 2 mod N -> x ^ 4 mod -> ... x ^ 2 |log y| mod N
```

Modular exponentiation algorithm makes assumptions that:

```
x ^ y == (x ^ |y/2|) ^ 2 if y is even
x ^ y == x * ((x ^ |y/2|) ^ 2) if y is odd
```

And so recursive modular exponentiation algorithm will look like this in java:

```
/**
* Modular exponentiation algorithm
* @param x Assumption: x >= 0
* @param y Assumption: y >= 0
* @param N Assumption: N > 0
* @return x ^ y mod N
*/
public static long modExp(long x, long y, long N) {
    if(y == 0)
        return 1 % N;

    long z = modExp(x, Math.abs(y/2), N);

    if(y % 2 == 0)
        return (long) ((Math.pow(z, 2)) % N);
    return (long) ((x * Math.pow(z, 2)) % N);
}
```

Special thanks to [@chux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux) for found mistake with incorrect return value in case of y and 0 comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. May you please provide input data which leads to incorrect output?

Comment: Thanks a lot for found mistake. I've corrected to 1 % N.