# Calculation of modulus with high powers

Tags: android, math

how should i calculate modulus of very high powers. like 9^53 mod 25. and if possible can anyone help me with its code in android. Thanks in advance

Comment: This has already been asked before.  Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`BigInteger.modPow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) method or an equivalent solution that uses an efficient [modular exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) algorithm.