# Why do programming contests want answers modulo some large prime?

Tags: math, primes, modulus

I have been testing the waters of competitive programming and I have already seen this statement mentioned a lot of times:

> Print the result modulo 10<sup>9</sup> + 7

Now I can figure out that this is some way of preventing overflow of digits when dealing with very large numbers. But how and why does it work? I would be grateful if someone could explain the mathematical reasoning behind this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers

Comment: @gtgaxiola- I'm not sure that question is particularly relevant here. I think the question here is "why work modulo 1,000,000,007?" versus "how do you exponentiate modulo a large number?"

Comment: @templatetypedef you are right. Its not difficult to learn how to do it. I wanted to know why its done.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Many contest questions ask you to compute some very, very large number (say, the number of permutations of an 150-element sequence containing some large number of duplicates). Many programming languages don't natively support arbitrary-precision arithmetic, so in the interest of fairness it makes sense for those contests not to ask you for the exact value. The challenge, then, is the following: how can the contest site know when you have the right answer given that you can't exactly compute it?

One initially appealing option would be to just ask for the answer modulo some large power of two (say, 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup>) so that competitors working in languages like C or C++ could just use `uint32_t` or `uint64_t`s to do all the computations, letting overflows occur normally, and then submit the results. However, this isn't particularly desirable. Suppose, for example, that the question is the following:

> Compute 10,000!

This number is staggeringly huge and is way too big to fit into a 32-bit or 64-bit unsigned integer. However, if you just want to get the answer modulo 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup>, you could just use this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    puts("0");
}
```

The reason for this is that 10,000! is the product of at least 5,000 even numbers, so one of its factors is 2<sup>5,000</sup>. Therefore, if you just want the answer modulo 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup>, you don't actually have to compute it at all. You can just say that the result is 0 mod 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup>.

The problem here is that working modulo 2<sup>32</sup> or 2<sup>64</sup> is troublesome if the resulting answer is cleanly divisible by either of those numbers. However, if we work modulo a large *prime* number, then this trick wouldn't work. As an example, the number 7,897,987 is prime. If you try to compute 10,000! mod 7,897,987, then you can't just say "the answer is 0" because none of the numbers multiplied together in 10,000! are divisors of 7,897,987. You'd actually have to do some work to figure out what this number is modulo that large prime. More generally, working modulo a large prime usually requires you to compute the actual answer modulo that large prime, rather than using number-theoretic tricks to skip all the work entirely.

So why work modulo 1,000,000,007? This number happens to be prime (so it's good to use as a modulus) and it's less than 2<sup>31</sup> - 1, the largest possible value you can fit in a signed 32-bit integer. The signedness is nice here because in some languages (like Java) there are no unsigned integer types and the default integer type is a 32-bit signed integer. This means that you can work modulo 1,000,000,007 without risking an integer overflow.

To summarize:

- Working modulo a large prime makes it likely that if your program produces the correct output, it actually did some calculation and did so correctly.
- Working modulo 1,000,000,007 allows a large number of languages to use their built-in integer types to store and calculate the result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Excellently explained. Thanks for this :)

Comment: @templatetypedef Why 10^9 + 7? Why can't it be 2^31-1 which is also a prime itself or 2,147,483,629?

Comment: I think this is because by picking a number less than INT_MAX you give a little clearance above the threshold so that people can exceed the limit without triggering an integer overflow. Note that 2 &times; (10^9 + 7) still fits in an integer.

Comment: is there a way to find out actual answer when used this method? eg: n! in modulo M gives x but actual value of n! is y. can we reach to y using x and M?

Comment: There are infinitely many numbers that leave a remainder of x modulo M, so without any other external information there’s no way to recover y purely from M and x.

Comment: @JohnSolomon It also makes it easy to compute `(a+b) modulo M` when M=10^9+7, as 2M still fits into an `int` and hence `(a+b)` is guaranteed to not overflow. Otherwise we would have to explicitly cast like `((long long)(a) + b) % M`. Or declare a and b as `long long`. Since almost every problem involves addition, that will make `int`s barely usable.