# does modulus function is only applicable on integer data types?

Tags: c

my algorithm calculates the  arithmetic operations given below,for small values it works perfectly but for large numbers such as 218194447 it returns a random value,I have tried to use long long int,double but nothing works because **modulus function** which I have used can only be used with int types , can anyone explain how to solve it or could provide a links that can be useful

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    long long i,j;
    int t,n;

    scanf("%d\n",&t);

    while(t--)
    {
        scanf("%d",&n);

        long long k;
        i = (n*n);
        k = (1000000007);
        j = (i % k);

        printf("%d\n",j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please indent/format your code so that it's readable.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers

Comment: Unrelated: just using `1000000007` would seem considerably clearer than recomputing `pow(10,9)+7` repeatedly, which we can only hope a reasonably intelligent compiler optimized anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah correct but that doesn't change much

Comment: @user3315556 besides the clarity of the code and its performance, nothing at all (thus the comment and not a answer, the link provided by R.T should be considered for potential answer-material).

Comment: How do you know that the value is random?

Comment: @JoelCornett because it is represented with a -ve sign in the beginning that represents overflow of memory I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare your variables as `int64_t` or `long long` ; then they would compute the modulus in their range (e.g. 64 bits for `int64_t`). And it would work correctly only if all intermediate values fit in their range.

However, you probably want or need [bignums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). I suggest you to learn and use [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/) for that.

BTW, don't use `pow` since it computes in floating point. Try `i = n * n;` instead of `i = pow(n,2);`

<sup>P.S. this is not for a beginner in C programming, using *gmplib* requires some fluency with C programming (and programming in general)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that intermittent values of your computation exceed the range of values that can be stored in an int. n^2 for values of n>2^30 cannot be represented as int.

Follow the link above given by R.T. for a way of doing modulo on big numbers. That won't be enough though, since you also need a class/library that can handle big integer values . With only standard C libraries in place, that will otherwise be a though task do do on your own. (ok, for 2^31, a 64 bit integer would do, but if you're going even larger, you're out of luck again)

Answer (score 0):

After accept answer

To find the modulo of a number `n` raised to some power `p` (2 in OP's case), there is no need to *first* calculate `power(n,p)`.  Instead calculate intermediate modulo values as `n` is raise to intermediate powers.

The following code works with `p==2` as needed by OP, but also works quickly if `p=1000000000`.

The only wider integers needed are integers that are twice as wide as `n`.

Performing all this with unsigned integers simplifies the needed code.

The resultant code is quite small.

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t powmod(uint32_t base, uint32_t expo, uint32_t mod) {
  // `y = 1u % mod` needed only for the cases expo==0, mod<=1
  // otherwise `y = 1u` would do.
  uint32_t y = 1u % mod;

  while (expo) {
    if (expo & 1u) {
      y = ((uint64_t) base * y) % mod;
    }
    expo >>= 1u;
    base = ((uint64_t) base * base) % mod;
  }

  return y;
}

#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main(void) {
  unsigned long j;
  unsigned t, n;

  scanf("%u\n", &t);

  while (t--) {
    scanf("%u", &n);

    unsigned long k;
    k = 1000000007u;
    j = powmod(n, 2, k);

    printf("%lu\n", j);
  }

  return 0;
}
```