# Java - Modulus function fails on large numbers

Tags: java, bigdecimal, modulus

I am working on RSA algo but the numbers, on which different operations are performed, are very large. And Java operators are failing here.

I need to take modulus of a very large number (like this big `1.35858791876006E+75`) but the normal `%` or `bigDecimalObj.divideAndRemainder()` function does not give me the correct answer.

Is there any other library (some .jar file) available that could help me out?

Comment: Can you show how you are trying?

Comment: There are algorithms for finding out modulus. See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177781/how-to-calculate-modulus-of-large-numbers

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"

Comment: I think, standard Java classes can do this if used properly. Show us how you use them.

Comment: I was simply doing `1.35858791876006E+75 % 77` and the answers given by Java and Windows' calculator were different, while calculator's answer was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), it can handle big numbers. More specifically using [mod()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#mod%28java.math.BigInteger%29) and [modpow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) can solve many overflow issues.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank you for the answer, it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should use BigInteger, You can look it from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html