# BigInteger method mod() performance is bad. Is there a better trade off for huge numbers?

Tags: java, performance, biginteger, modulo

If you try inputs 99999999999999999 100000 for the code below it runs the logic at about 5 seconds. I've searched for the bottle neck and found out it is the mod() method. Is there a better trade off for huge numbers?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FibonacciHuge {

    private static BigInteger calcFibMod( long n , long m ) {
        Table table = new Table( n );
        BigInteger mBI = new BigInteger( String.valueOf( m ) );
        BigInteger first = new BigInteger( "0" );
        BigInteger second = new BigInteger( "1" );
        BigInteger result;
        while ( true ) {
            result = second.add( first );
            first = second;
            second = result;

            if ( table.add( result.mod( mBI ) ) ) {
                return table.found;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        long n = scanner.nextLong();
        long m = scanner.nextLong();
        System.out.println( calcFibMod( n , m ) );
    }

    static final class Table {

        List<BigInteger> mods;
        BigInteger found;
        long n;
        int size;

        Table( long n ) {
            this.n = n;
            mods = new ArrayList<>();
            mods.add( BigInteger.ZERO );
            mods.add( BigInteger.ONE );
            size = 2;
        }

        boolean add( BigInteger mod ) {
            mods.add( mod );
            size++;

            if ( !( BigInteger.ONE.equals( mod ) && BigInteger.ZERO.equals( mods.get( size - 2 ) ) ) ) {
                return false;
            }

            mods.remove( size - 1 );
            mods.remove( size - 2 );
            n++;
            size = mods.size();
            long rest = n % size;
            long index = rest == 0l
                         ? size - 1
                         : rest - 1;

            found = mods.get( ( int ) index );
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33223058/829571

Comment: `mod` might be the most expensive part of your code but that doesn't mean it can actually be optimized further.  It's hard to tell from your code, but frankly it looks a lot like the math you're trying to do is just plain expensive.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287144/modulus-power-of-big-numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of storing a large number, store that number mod mBI, and your mod operation won't take so long.  If you replace

```
result = second.add( first );
```

with

```
result = second.add( first ).mod( mBI );
```

and make your condition `table.add( result )` instead of `table.add (result.mod( mBI ) )`, you get much better performance.

Comment: thanks @user2791611 , but I need to keep the result of second.add(first) for the next loop.

Comment: @juliocnsouza From what I can see, you don't actually need the result, you need the result mod mBI.  You only ever use the result mod mBI.  I did test this code on the two inputs you gave in the question, and it gives the same result in much less time.  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: thanks @user2791611 you are right, it worked much faster! I really don't know what a did I in the first test that made me come with the conclusion commented above. Thanks for the answer and for getting my attention to it :D .