# Math behind "compute n! under modulo p"?

Tags: c++, math, modulo, factorial

```
long long x;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    x = (x * i) % m;
}
cout << x;
```

This is the trick to calculate (n!) mod m (assume m > n). However, I don't know why it's true. Can you explain the math mechanism behind this?

Comment: This question should be moved to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hvd well than it should be closed ;-)

Comment: No. In this case m should be larger than n.

Comment: @JulianHeinovski Actually looking more closely it wouldn't be a duplicate of that. I'm sure it's been asked before though, let me see if I can find a better link.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346271/rules-for-algebra-equations-involving-modulo-operations/346277 does hint at why this works.

Comment: There is no trick here, it's all straightforward. Which part do you think involves a trick?

Comment: If you want a short answer, there's a proof for it, which I'm pretty sure you can find it if you type "modular arithmetic properties" on google

Comment: Basic (and easily provable) property of modulo arithmetic.   `(a * b) % m == ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m`   (non-zero `m`).

Comment: it's just simply [modulo math](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177781/995714), just like how you do [modular exponentiation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8496182/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea here is that you can take the modulus before, during, or after multiplication and get the same value after taking the modulus of the final result.

As @Peter points out,

```
(a * b) % m == ((a % m) * (b % m)) % m
```

For the factorial,

```
n! = 1 * 2 * 3 * ... * (n-1) * n
```

so we have

```
n! % m = (((((((1 * 2) % m) * 3) % m) * ... * n-1) % m) * n) % m
```

taking the modulus after each iteration.

---

The advantage to doing it this way is that your number won't blow up and overflow your long long type like it would do pretty quickly if you didn't take intermediate modulus values.